# C++11 How to store pointers-to-methods in std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to store in `std::unordered_map<object, std::vector<pointer>>` pair of object and vector of pointers to methods of that object. `object` can refer to any class `T` and `pointer` must contain pointers to methods from `T` instance. I must be able to call those methods later. I tried to use `boost::any`, but I was not able to call methods later. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use std::function< void() >.

```
std::map<object, std::vector<std::function<void()> > functions;
```

consider to use std::bind if you need to bind some member functions and put them in.

Or if you don't like this you can a use pure virtual interfaces and store it to your vector
IObject{
 virtual void doSomething()=0;
};

```
std::map<object, std::vector<IObject*> > functions;
```

then use it to call doSomething.